# Mount NFS share and symlink it to a directory using non-Administrator account

Tags: nfs, python, windows-8.1

I'm on Windows 8.1 Enterprise and what I'm trying to do is to have a python script that will:

1. Mount an NFS share for the current user
2. Create a symlink in the current working directory to a drive mapped to this share

And this seems to be impossible: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320550 I have to run script as an administrator in order to create symlink. In other hand I have to mount NFS volume from the current user so it will be able to access it.

I have no idea how to make part of my script to run using the current user privileges and another part using elevated privileges.

Comment: Why create a symlink, why not map it to a drive letter?

Comment: @mdpc This is indeed could be solution, however there are requirements to keep the thing the same on all the supported platforms (OSX, Ubuntu,  Windows): mount to a specific path.